# Printing a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to learn Linkedlist in C++.I was trying to insert new nodes in the list and display them.
But while displaying the linked list i get some random values.The program keeps on running and does not stop at all.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
  int data;
  node *next;
};

int main()
{
  int ch;
  char ch1;
  do
  {

    cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Adding the first node"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Adding a new node"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Printing the list"<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    node *n;
    node *t;
    node *h;
    switch(ch)
    {
      case 1:
        n=new node;
        int x;
        cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        n->data=x;
        t=n;
        h=n;
        cout<<"Do you want to continue";
        cin>>ch1;
        break;

      case 2:
        n=new node;
        int y;
        cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
        cin>>y;
        n->data=y;
        t->next=n;
        t=t->next;
        cout<<"Do you want to continue";
        cin>>ch1;
        break;

      case 3:
        do
        {   while(h->next!=NULL)
          {


            cout<<h->data<<endl;
            h=h->next;
          }
        }while(h!=NULL);
        break;
    }
  }while(ch1=='y' || ch1=='Y');
}
```

Comment: 1. you are not setting t->next = NULL when adding either first element or next element.   2. In your iteartion, you aare modifying you head pointer. you should assign to temp pointer and then iterate. 3. You are using do while and while why? 4. You are accepting character and matching with int?

Comment: You don't initialize `t` before using it in case 2.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think he assumes it will have already been assigned to `n` in case 1 before the user chooses case 2.

Comment: A better way to implement this would be to have dedicated linked list functions like `append()`, `print()`, etc. so you can narrow down problems like these. It's also easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set next to null for first node:

```
case 1:
n=new node;
n->next = NULL;//this
int x;
cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
cin>>x;
n->data=x;
t=n;
h=n;
n->
cout<<"Do you want to continue";
cin>>ch1;
break;
```

and for last node too:

```
case 2:
n=new node;
int y;
cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
cin>>y;
n->data=y;
n->next=NULL;//here too
t->next=n;
t=t->next;

cout<<"Do you want to continue";
cin>>ch1;
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that you are traversing the head pointer `h=h->next;` to display values so  if you try to display the list for second time it will not display anything .
Instead traversing head pointer use temporary pointer and also change the condition 
`while(h->next!=NULL)` to `while(t!=null)` in order to display the last element in list

```
t=h;

while(t!=NULL)
{
    cout<<t->data<<endl;
    t=t->next;
}
```